# How to detect and maybe eliminate Malware from 'Flash Player'?

Tags: macos, security, malware, adobe-flash, virus

I read about that some websites do claim you have old Adobe Flash Player installed.

I am not sure whether or not I got such notifications legitimately or not. 
I know I have downloaded some Flash updates and now want to 
a) detect whether my Flash updates were malware 
b) if so, how I can delete the malware.

I think that simply deleting Flash from Applications is not doing it or is it?

Using the newest MacOS on iMac.

Comment: **Flash Player** is a browser plugin (not an application) with a preference pane in **System Preferences**.  The only place you should be getting _any_ downloads or updates is from the source (in this case **Adobe**) - where did you get it?

Comment: @red_menace I don't know exactly. I remember getting quite regularly some update suggestions, upon which I updated my stuff. Whether or not they were real, I don't know. That is why I want to look whether or not I have malware instead more closely now.